# Best way to compress output with Rails and Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression

I want to serve up all my content gzipped.  I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 and the server has Apache/Phusion.  I can see two main ways to compress output:

1. Use an `after_filter` like the output_compression plugin
2. Use .htaccess file

Which way is more efficient? Is there a better way?

It looks like the output_compression plugin is fairly old.  From my little experience with Rails, it looks like it would still work with Rails 3, but I'm not sure.

Also, if I use an `after_filter`, static files won't be compressed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very much want to use mod_deflate:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

It takes care of compressing all files served from the apache instance.